# What is the correct way to calculate flux across given surface?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, surface-integrals

Suppose I need to find the flux of vector Field $\vec{F} = <y^2, xz , -1>,$ across the cone  $z = 2\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}$ between the planes $z = 0$ and $z = 2$,

As we can see, there will be two surfaces  $S_1$ the conical part and $S_2$ the circular part on top of the cone of radius  $1$ .

My question is : Do I need to find the flux  through each of the surfaces or do I need to just find it acroos $S_1$ ?,

I have solved a number of questions like these , sometimes the problem is solved just by considering it across $S_1$(ie the conical part) , while some time I also have to take care of $S_2$ the circular part.

Can anyone please tell me in detail when Do I have to include both the surfaces and when do I have to exclude one ?

(The given problem is from Thomas Calculus, and the flux is calculated simply by considering $S_1$)

Thank you

Comment: The way the problem is stated, they're not counting the disk as part of the surface.  The surface is "the _cone_ between the planes", not the planes themselves.

Comment: @B.Goddard : I think you are correct , But our teacher gave us one question(had the same language as this one) where we had to consider the disc also, due to which I am confused whether we have to consider the top disc or not .

Comment: Perhaps the other question said something like, "Find the flux through the surface of the solid bound by the cone and the plane."

Comment: This was the question given by my teacher  : "Find the flux of $<x^2,y^2>$ across the surface of cone $z^2 = x^2  + y^2$ bounded by $z = 0 $ and $z =3$ ", the answer to this problem is $\frac{81\pi(\sqrt{2} + 1)}{2}$, and  can be calculated only if you consider the flux across the top disc.

Answer (score 1):

If the problem asks for the flux through the surface, I cant imagine why you would calculate it through only part of the surface!  Could you give an example in which you "I have solved a number of questions like these , sometimes the problem is solved just by considering it across S1 (ie the conical part)"?